# Back to Previous ViewController

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tabbed application project in Xcode and I'm trying to create a back button for one of the `viewcontrollers` in order to go back to the previous view. You can get to this `viewcontroller` from 2 different `viewcontrollers` so I'm wondering if it's possible to pop the `viewcontroller` in order to go back to the correct view controller(the one you were previously on). This code doesn't seem to work with `tabBarController`.

```
-(IBAction) goBack: (id)sender{
[self.tabBarController popViewControllerAnimated: YES]; }
```

Comment: A tab bar controller does not manage a stack of view controllers. Since a tab bar controller allows random access to its tabs there is no hierarchy that indicates a previous view controller. If you have a back button that changes to a different tab you most likely have a design issue. Tabs should generally be completely independent of each other.

Comment: I have a tabbarcontroller, 2 controllers have a button that is linked to an independent view controller(not on the tab bar). Is there a better way of doing this?  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *array = [self. tabBarController viewControllers];

[self.tabBarController popToViewController:[array objectAtIndex:2] animated:YES];
```

Think this one works . Havent tested it . Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

check this.

```
id controller = [self.tabBarController selectedViewController];
        if([controller isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
        {
            [controller popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }
```

Comment: This is crashing but I think I've confused myself and explained it incorrectly. I'm going from a ViewController to two possible tabbarcontrollers.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *array = [self. tabBarController viewControllers];
for (UIViewController *controller in array) {
    if ([controller isKindOfClass:[ReachViewControllerName class]]) {
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:controller
                                              animated:YES];
        break;
    }
}
```

May be it ll helps.